# Auto FTP-Sync with Aptana-Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ftp, aptana, synchronization

I'm using Aptana 3.2.2 Eclipse (Juno) Plugin after i added a ftp connection within the project i can synchronize files manual not automatic! In some tutorials the write there should be an checkbox for that (within the connection/more options) but there is no one?
Can anybody help me?

When i open the file directly over ftp i don't have function check/complete

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but. . . (now in V3.6.1)

1. goto the App Explorer (window -> show view -> app explorer)
2. select your project
3. Publish** -> Deployment settings 
   *(**in app explorer, looks like a little box or envelope)*
4. At the bottom, "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site"